# How to Combine and Sell multiple iOS Apps as one package

Tags: ios, app-store

We have more then 10 separate apps on app store. But now we want to sell all these apps as one package, so user will have paid once only for all 10 apps. Is it possible on App store?

Comment: No, I'm afraid this is currently not possible.

Comment: so, can you please give me any alternate if you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ideal but:

Alternative could be for the user to download one of the apps (for free). This app contains a store which lists the other apps in the group and allows easy download (also free). Store also offers a pack activation purchase which enables the core features of all the apps. This generates a record for the user on your server and / or a number of hashed identifiers. The user can tap a number of buttons to open the other apps using the hashed identifiers (custom URL scheme) or use a restore button in the other apps which checks your server before checking with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you allow the apps to be installed for free, and then use in-app purchasing to acquire a license to run any of the 10 applications. This approach does not require implementing a store of your own.

Comment: Yes, we can do like that but if we have 500 devices then we will have to make transaction in all the devices. we wants to remove this multiple payment transaction.